# ssrs report generation to word fotramt

Tags: reporting-services

i am new to ssrs facing some issue..my goal is to export .rdl to .word format.

first issue:
 designed one row with textbox1 static column name and joined one more textbox2 in that dynamic values coming from database that inserted into like table.
when exporting the file to word ,the values are coming outside of the textbox and there is no proper alignment.
Second Issue:
i created on date set and based on that drawn one table and passing policy id if no value means row name is not visible..i am expecting @ least row name should be there if value is not there need to ZERO value to the user,,

before passing policy id image----

[here one row towing and labour one row is there..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYr9o.png)

after passing policy id:
[row name is not visible and need to show row name with ZERO if no value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6J0H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your question is your textbox need to show ZERO if no value

Here is the solution:

1. Right click the target textbox
2. TextBox Properties
3. General -> Value
4. Enter expression like this

   ```
   =IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Fields!YourField.Value), 0, Fields!YourField.Value)
   ```

   or

   ```
   =IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ReportItems!Textbox1.Value), 0, ReportItems!Textbox1.Value)
   ```

Comment: yes exactly tried same like  expression=IIF(isnothing(fields!fieldname.value),0,fields!fieldname.value)        2.problem

Comment: Thanks for great solution.